# how can we get like "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>" by using castor

Tags: xml, xsd, castor, xml-declaration

by using normal xml am able to get standalone="yes" attribute with "xml" tag. But when I am trying to get like following by using CASTOR XML am unable. answer will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Comment: are you trying to use castor to compose xml?

Comment: yes, am trying to marshalling  java Object to xml by using Castor mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

Castor by default generate the XML declaration as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

In my investigation I didn't get any castor mapping configuration to generate customized XML declaration. So, we can handle it as follows,

```
writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
```

After appending our own XML declaration to writer, we need to suppress Castor not to generate the XML declaration.

```
marshaller.setSupressXMLDeclaration(true);
```